# Why isn't fiddler capturing request when invoking XMLRPC from iis?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, fiddler

I have a webapplication written in .NET, that utilizes CookComputing.XmlRpcV2 for xmlrpc-communication.

When I invoke my unit-tests in Visual Studio 2008, fiddler2 captures the actual xmlrpc-requests successfully, but when I'm running the actual application under IIS7 it shows nothing. I have verified that it actually invokes the xmlrpc-requests in my firewall, but I need to see the content of the requests for debugging purposes.

I have issued an iisreset with fiddler running in an attempt to see if IIS actually fetches proxysettings from WinINET upon app-start, but it didn't help.

Do IIS have it's own proxy-settings per app? Or if it's part of ASP.NET... I can't seem to find any information about it.

I could of course define my own proxy-server in the WebRequest somehow in code, but since I just want to utilize the proxy for debugging purposes, I'd rather find a simpler solution.

This is Vista, running iis7 with .NET 3.5 SP1. Fiddler2 version 2.1.9.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default proxy setting is per user.  What identity is IIS running under?

Comment: w3wp.exe is runned under NETWORK SERVICE of course... meaning I could switch the application pool to my default user, right? I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answer to [Setting Registry Key For All Users In C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088221/setting-registry-key-for-all-users-in-c).  It refers to http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1147/ which suggests creating a ProxySettingsPerUser registry setting and with a 0 DWORD value.

Comment: Nice suggestion, I will try it out and see if it works on Windows 7, that would be really helpful on my dev-machine.

Comment: I really tried to get this to work, but when enabling system wide settings, then fiddler isn't allowed to modify the proxy-settings, it seems, in Windows 7. It's too bad, since it would have been really handy.