# How can I get Fiddler to display information about a web service request made from my ASP.NET code behind?

Tags: web-services, fiddler

I have an ASPX page.  When the page is loaded there is code in the code behind that uses an API.  The API makes an HTTPS call out to a third party, commercial web service.  I am trying to troubleshoot why the API calls are not working properly.  Apparently the API actually constructs an XML request that is sent out over HTTPS to the web service.  I've been told by the support rep that I need to provide them with the XML that is being sent.  The only way I can figure out how to get the XML is to use a tool like Fiddler to see what is being sent out.  So how can I use Fiddler to see the contents of the XML request that is being sent from the server out to the web service?  I am running everything directly on the server but all I am seeing is the GET request for the ASPX file itself.  I am not seeing anything in relation to the HTTPS request that the server code is sending out to the web service.  I have not used Fiddler much so I am hoping that maybe I just don't have it set up right to monitor that traffic.

Corey

Answer (score 1):

After mucking around with it a bit I found this post:  [Why isn't fiddler capturing request when invoking XMLRPC from iis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700463/why-isnt-fiddler-capturing-request-when-invoking-xmlrpc-from-iis).  That seemed to do the trick!  Basically it sounds like the default proxy settings in Win7 are on a per user basis.  So I went in and changed the identity of the AppPool for my site to a local user (Administrator) and then it worked great.  I started up Fiddler.  Then I started up my ASP.NET app and then when I loaded the page I saw the request that went out to the web service from my code behind!  Yay!